# Get the list of files from a Snowflake stage?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The goal is to copy only the last few files from a stage to a table (based on date). I'm trying to find a straight forward way in snowflake to do that.

I know there's `LIST` command that give the list of files based on the pattern. But that is not useable (as in you can't use it in a select statement).
There JS solutions for this scenario, which is a bit hacky, but is there anyway I can copy files based on filename/pattern and datemodified from stage to a table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pattern parameter to achieve this requirement where in you can select the specific set of files based on the criteria. Details and samples are here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#syntax

Sample using pattern matching: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#loading-using-pattern-matching

Comment: yeah I know that, this resolve the filename issue, how about date. Pattern matching gives/copies all files that matches the pattern, but I want to filter/select based on dates=? "give/copy all files that matches the pattern and loaded to stage in the last three days" this is what I'm looking for

Comment: One other way is to have the external location be configured such that it will have only the files (latest or the ones with last day <= 3 days) using a polling mechanism on the external location. As in have the files loaded to a temp location and from there put to the staged location.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Snowpipe, with auto-ingest set to false, and use:

```
alter pipe <pipe_name> refresh PREFIX = ‘<path>’ MODIFIED_AFTER = <start_time>;
```

With MODIFIED_AFTER being a time stamp (in ISO-8601 format) of the oldest file you want to load based on the LAST_MODIFIED date (i.e. date when a file was staged).

See more info & example here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-pipe.html#alter-pipe

Note - The REFRESH functionality is not intended for regular use.

I think the only other option if you don't want to use Snowpipe, would be to use the 'FILES =' parameter to only ingest the specific files you want, you then have control to include the files manually only if you wish based on their last_modified date - but if you have a high volume of files, this is not viable (unless you do it programmatically, but then you're moving away from the straightforward solution you are after). https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#optional-parameters

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT METADATA$FILENAME
FROM @stage/prefix
WHERE ...;
```

This gives you much more power/possibilities, and you can even filter based on [the other metadata columns](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata#metadata-columns) (such as `METADATA$FILE_LAST_MODIFIED > CURRENT_DATE()`, for example).

And it can be easily embedded into CTEs, subqueries, joins, etc!

And obviously, you can add those same filters in a [`COPY INTO` command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table) (or just use [Snowpipe](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro) to load new files automatically as they arrive).